# How to improve a coord.polar() plot to visualise the intersection of different patterns?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I would like to visualise the timing of occupancy and device patterns. For example I would like to know the time when people are at home, the are with their partner and they use an electric device. So, the timing of the synchronisation of these behaviour.

I created the above plot for different individuals. Each individual behaviour pattern is represented during a day.

[image]

Even though the plot highlight different patterns is not clear when all three patterns occur. Is there a  way to highlight the timing of synchronisation?  Any help is welcomed. Thanks

I share the data.frame:

```
dput(tail(df5))
structure(list(id = c(99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 99L), variable = structure(115:120, .Label = c("04:00", 
"04:10", "04:20", "04:30", "04:40", "04:50", "05:00", "05:10", 
"05:20", "05:30", "05:40", "05:50", "06:00", "06:10", "06:20", 
"06:30", "06:40", "06:50", "07:00", "07:10", "07:20", "07:30", 
"07:40", "07:50", "08:00", "08:10", "08:20", "08:30", "08:40", 
"08:50", "09:00", "09:10", "09:20", "09:30", "09:40", "09:50", 
"10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", "10:40", "10:50", "11:00", 
"11:10", "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", "11:50", "12:00", "12:10", 
"12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", "13:00", "13:10", "13:20", 
"13:30", "13:40", "13:50", "14:00", "14:10", "14:20", "14:30", 
"14:40", "14:50", "15:00", "15:10", "15:20", "15:30", "15:40", 
"15:50", "16:00", "16:10", "16:20", "16:30", "16:40", "16:50", 
"17:00", "17:10", "17:20", "17:30", "17:40", "17:50", "18:00", 
"18:10", "18:20", "18:30", "18:40", "18:50", "19:00", "19:10", 
"19:20", "19:30", "19:40", "19:50", "20:00", "20:10", "20:20", 
"20:30", "20:40", "20:50", "21:00", "21:10", "21:20", "21:30", 
"21:40", "21:50", "22:00", "22:10", "22:20", "22:30", "22:40", 
"22:50", "23:00", "23:10", "23:20", "23:30", "23:40", "23:50", 
"00:00", "00:10", "00:20", "00:30", "00:40", "00:50", "01:00", 
"01:10", "01:20", "01:30", "01:40", "01:50", "02:00", "02:10", 
"02:20", "02:30", "02:40", "02:50", "03:00", "03:10", "03:20", 
"03:30", "03:40", "03:50"), class = "factor"), athome = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Not at home", "At home"), class = "factor"), 
    usedev = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Not using device", 
    "Using device"), class = "factor"), withspouseorpartner = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Not reported", "Reported"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = 21595:21600, class = "data.frame")
```

Code that I used to create the plot:

```
df5$athome <- factor(df5$athome)
levels(df5$athome) <- c("Not at home", "At home")

df5$usedev <- factor(df5$usedev)
levels(df5$usedev) <- c("Not using device", "Using device")


df5$withspouseorpartner <- factor(df5$withspouseorpartner)
levels(df5$withspouseorpartner) <- c("Not reported", "Reported")


plot<-ggplot(df5, aes(variable, id)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = athome, alpha = 0.5)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = usedev, alpha = 0.5)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = withspouseorpartner, alpha = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("At home" = "red", 
                               "Not at home" = "white",
                               "Not using device" = "transparent",
                               "Not reported"="transparent",
                               "Reported"="yellow",
                               "Using device" = "#0000FF88"))+ labs(x="Time (hours)", y="Individuals identification number", title=" Occupancy and device use", fill="Behaviour")+theme_bw() 
plot + coord_polar()+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = ))+  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c( "04:00","05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00","13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00"), expand = c(0,0)) +scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

Tail of the data set:

```
tail(df5, 100)
      id variable      athome           usedev withspouseorpartner
21501 99    07:20 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21502 99    07:30 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21503 99    07:40     At home     Using device        Not reported
21504 99    07:50 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21505 99    08:00 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21506 99    08:10 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21507 99    08:20 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21508 99    08:30 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21509 99    08:40 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21510 99    08:50 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21511 99    09:00 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21512 99    09:10 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21513 99    09:20 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21514 99    09:30 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21515 99    09:40 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21516 99    09:50 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21517 99    10:00 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21518 99    10:10 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21519 99    10:20 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21520 99    10:30 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21521 99    10:40 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21522 99    10:50 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21523 99    11:00     At home     Using device        Not reported
21524 99    11:10     At home     Using device        Not reported
21525 99    11:20 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21526 99    11:30 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21527 99    11:40 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21528 99    11:50 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21529 99    12:00 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21530 99    12:10     At home     Using device        Not reported
21531 99    12:20     At home     Using device        Not reported
21532 99    12:30 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21533 99    12:40 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21534 99    12:50 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21535 99    13:00 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21536 99    13:10 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21537 99    13:20 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21538 99    13:30 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21539 99    13:40 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21540 99    13:50 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21541 99    14:00 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21542 99    14:10 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21543 99    14:20 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21544 99    14:30 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21545 99    14:40 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21546 99    14:50 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21547 99    15:00 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21548 99    15:10     At home     Using device        Not reported
21549 99    15:20 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21550 99    15:30 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21551 99    15:40 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21552 99    15:50 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21553 99    16:00 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21554 99    16:10 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21555 99    16:20 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21556 99    16:30 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21557 99    16:40 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21558 99    16:50     At home     Using device        Not reported
21559 99    17:00 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21560 99    17:10     At home     Using device        Not reported
21561 99    17:20 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21562 99    17:30 Not at home     Using device        Not reported
21563 99    17:40 Not at home     Using device            Reported
21564 99    17:50 Not at home     Using device            Reported
21565 99    18:00 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21566 99    18:10 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21567 99    18:20 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21568 99    18:30 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21569 99    18:40 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21570 99    18:50 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21571 99    19:00 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21572 99    19:10 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21573 99    19:20 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21574 99    19:30 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21575 99    19:40 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21576 99    19:50 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21577 99    20:00 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21578 99    20:10 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21579 99    20:20 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21580 99    20:30 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21581 99    20:40 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21582 99    20:50 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21583 99    21:00 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21584 99    21:10 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21585 99    21:20 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21586 99    21:30     At home Not using device            Reported
21587 99    21:40     At home Not using device            Reported
21588 99    21:50     At home Not using device            Reported
21589 99    22:00 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21590 99    22:10 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21591 99    22:20 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21592 99    22:30 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21593 99    22:40 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21594 99    22:50 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21595 99    23:00 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21596 99    23:10 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21597 99    23:20 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21598 99    23:30 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21599 99    23:40 Not at home Not using device            Reported
21600 99    23:50 Not at home Not using device            Reported
```

Comment: can you share the tail of your dataframe ? (for now, there is not enough reproducible example to be able to fit multiple categories)

Comment: Thanks, with a `dput`, it will be easier ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way will be to use `interaction` into your `aes`, such as :

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x = variable, y = id, fill = interaction(athome, usedev, withspouseorpartner)))+
  geom_tile(alpha = 0.5)+
  coord_polar()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = ))+  
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c( "04:00","05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00","13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00"), expand = c(0,0)) +scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

You can see that for your example, people at home with their partner and using their device is represented by the "purple" color.

If you want to highlight a particular combination,you can alternatively create a new categorical column with some "ifelse" statement such as:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
DF %>% mutate(NewCol = ifelse(athome == "At home" & usedev == "Using device" & withspouseorpartner == "Reported",
                              "All three","Not all three")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = id, fill = NewCol))+
  geom_tile(alpha = 0.5)+
  coord_polar()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = ))+  
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c( "04:00","05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00","13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00"), expand = c(0,0)) +scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

**Reproducible example**

In order to cover all type of possible combinations, I recreate your dataframe using random sampling:

```r
DF <- data.frame(id = rep(1:2,each = 144),
                 variable = format(seq(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 00:00:00", tz="GMT"), length.out=144*2, by='10 min'), '%H:%M'),
                 athome = sample(c("At home", "Not at home"), 144*2 , replace  = TRUE),
                 usedev = sample(c("Not using device", "Using device"),144*2 , replace = TRUE),
                 withspouseorpartner = sample(c("Not reported", "Reported"),144*2 ,replace = TRUE))
```